# How to apply adaptive pattern generation

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing

The method defined in one of the papers for Moving Object Extraction Method is as follows:

> The input of the proposed FLD-based RBF scheme is built in YCbCr color
>   space via three variables regarding perception with which to provide
>   support for a many digital video applications. These variables are
>   luminance (Y), blue-difference chroma (Cb), and red-difference chroma
>   (Cr). Accordingly, the color element of a pixel pt(x; y) uses Y, Cb,
>   and Cr values together to represent the intensity and color of each
>   pixel in each incoming video frame It. In order to provide for the
>   variable bit-rate video stream properties, it is necessary to produce
>   lower-dimensional discriminant patterns. This is achieved through use
>   of the optimal projection vectors though the FLD technique from the
>   continual influx of incoming frames in the discriminant pattern
>   extraction operation. The optimal projection vectors are obtained
>   through a procedure which maximizes the ratio of the between-class
>   scatter and the within-class scatter [32], [33]. The proposed method
>   split each incoming frame into N  N blocks, with the kth block xk
>   belonging to the ith class. Let the between-class scatter matrix be
>   determined as follows:

[image]

> and the within-class scatter matrix determined as follows:

[image]

Now there are some terms which i am confused with respect to Images:

1. What is luminance for an image with RGB values?
2. What is a class wrt an image?
3. What is a scatter matrix wrt an image?
4. How do i calculate Ni, and what is u, xk, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Relative luminance can be calculated [from linear RGB components](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/Color/sRGB):

   Y = 0.2126 R + 0.7152 G + 0.0722 B

   Some other conversions from RGB space to YCbCr can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr).
2. Class can be viewed as clustering. Via some dimension reduction and projection methods, the blocks in the image that share similar patterns will be clustered into one class for further processing in a lower dimension.
3. Scatter matrices are defined in your (1) and (2). They are a metric to reflect the similarity inter- and intra-classes. The matrices are suppose to be used in clustering the similar patterns while extracting the distinct ones. So the clustering process is implemented by adjustment of each block until `SB/SW` reaches the maximum value.
4. `Xk` is the luminance of the `kth` block, `ui` is the mean luminance value of all the blocks that belong to the `ith` class, and `u` is the mean of all `ui` (mean luminance of all the classes).  Not sure what is `Ni` (probably some weight factor that in proportional to the block number in each class).

Comment: `Class can be viewed as clustering` - Can you please elaborate how can make clusters in an image? Also how to make dimension reduction and projection?

Comment: @LhtLohit Although your application is not image compression, this page might be helpful. It shows how similar content in a image can be 'clustered'(binning) into one block with PCA, in which the image dimension is reduced. Thanks. http://theiszm.wordpress.com/2010/09/24/14-image-compression-2/

Comment: -How do i apply the formulas for between-class scatter and within-class scatter matrix on the image. What is a class? What is a scatter matrix? Please provide an answer wrt opencv. I am completely baffled and confused.